# Windows 10 Anniversary update has changed unicode icons on my website

Tags: html, css, windows, unicode

The latest Windows 10 Anniversary update has changed the unicode "eye" icon on my website, is there any way to have it display as originally intended?

I have attached screens below:

Eye icon before Windows 10 Anniversary update
[image: Icon before Windows 10 Anniversary update]
Eye icon after Windows 10 Anniversary update
[image: Icon after Windows 10 Anniversary update]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>    
    <p data-text="" class="glitch-single-letter"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a css text effect on which purposely causes the glitch and tear on the icon in case you are wondering.

Thanks.

Update I have tried HTML Entity (decimal) `&#128065;` and HTML Entity (hex) `&#x1f441;` as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748565/prevent-html-entity-conversion-to-emoji) but the icon remained unchanged.

Comment: I have tried HTML Entity (decimal) `&#128065;` and HTML Entity (hex) `&#x1f441;` as per this answer but the icon remained unchanged.

Comment: @James Donnelly. This is not a duplicate the answer you have provided is not applicable as it is a new Windows 10 specific problem. Please remove the duplication, I have edited the answer as you requested. Thank you.

Comment: This is affecting my WPF application too. I use the 'HIGH VOLTAGE SIGN' (U+26A1) (⚡) using Segoe UI font and after the Anniversary Update it now displays a more complex rendering. Visual Studio also displays the new rendering in the code editor (Consolas font) but no other application does (Word, Firefox, ...). Except Paint.Net - if I paste it in there it also includes a yellow fill that I cannot change. I'm trying to unserstand this to achieve consistency - probably have to resort to using an image.

Comment: The answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659949/inconsistent-unicode-emoji-glyphs-symbols) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip) questions explain (somewhat) and have a solution. Can't get it to work in XAML. Also, should all applications now have this as a font option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent Unicode characters from rendering as emoji in HTML from JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915485/how-to-prevent-unicode-characters-from-rendering-as-emoji-in-html-from-javascrip)