# Prevent font rendering as an emoji

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, electron, emoji

I'm trying to render a custom checkbox in an Electron app.

```css
:before {
    content: '✔';
}
```

It renders differently at random without any code changes:

[image]
[image]

It seems that it defaults to a font `Segoe UI Emoji`. Is it possible to force rendering as left picture (not as emoji)?

Comment: Could you try set the font family to "Segoe UI Symbol", monospace? Not sure if this works for Electron app, works for preventing it in Edge where it also default renders UI Emoji.

Comment: That seems to be working. Can't say 100% because it appeared at random though. Does this code also work in Mac & Linux, because I think they have different emoji fonts: `Apple Color Emoji` & `Noto Color Emoji`?

Comment: You can post it as an answer.

Comment: Your right Alex, I searched a bit more and think I found a solution but can't really test this but looking at the documation this could work.

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748565/prevent-html-entity-conversion-to-emoji, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208126/prevent-emoji-characters-from-showing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to override the Emoji rendering of a psuedo element. I would recommend trying to use a special unicode character. *U+FE0E (0xFE0E)*. Like so: `content: "\2714 \FE0E";`

`content: "[enter your emoji unicode here] \FE0E";`

I used this convert tool to get the right CSS unicode for the emoji to place inside the 'content': https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/

**About U+FE0E**

> This codepoint may change the appearance of the preceding character.
>   If that is a symbol, dingbat or emoji, U+FE0E forces it to be rendered
>   in a textual fashion as compared to a colorful image. The Unicode
>   standard defines some standardized variants. See also “Unicode symbol
>   as text or emoji” for a discussion of this codepoint.

Sources: https://codepoints.net/U+FE0E, https://mts.io/2015/04/21/unicode-symbol-render-text-emoji/

Example:

```css
.test:before {
  content: "✔";
}

.test2:before {
  content: "\2714 \FE0E";
}
```

```html
<!-- if your looking in Chrome or Firefox this will both look the same -->
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test2"></div>
```